# How do I access gravity form checkbox values

Tags: php, wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

I have a form from gravity forms in my Wordpress site that has an input field and two checkboxes.
I inspected the page and copy the exact same code from the inspector as you can see below:

```
<input name="input_1" id="input_3_1" type="text" value=“Michael” class="medium" tabindex="1" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false">

<input name="input_10.1" type="checkbox" value="sms" id="choice_3_10_1" tabindex="11" style="display: none;">

<input name="input_10.2” type="checkbox" value=“email” id="choice_3_10_1" tabindex="11" style="display: none;">
```

In my functions.php I want to access the email values and add to a specific post and the function looks like this:

```
add_action( 'gform_after_submission_3', 'set_post_content', 10, 2 );
function set_post_content( $entry, $form ) {

    $post = get_post(1);
    $post->post_content = "Contact form updated Name: ”. rgpost('input_1)’ . ‘ SMS: ’ .rgpost('input_10.1') . ‘ Email: ’ . rgpost('input_10.2)’;
    wp_update_post( $post );

}
```

UPDATE:
After more research, I then noticed that using $entry['10.1'] I can access the checkbox value.

Question: From the hook where I am (in functions.php) how can I evaluate if a checkbox has been checked?

I tried using isset but it doesn't seem to work and I dont see any error.

Comment: Syntax wise, there are at least two errors in your code: `rgpost('input_1)’` should be `rgpost('input_1')`, and `rgpost('input_10.2)’` should be `rgpost('input_10.2')`.

Comment: It might be a good idea to enable [WordPress' Debug log](https://wordpress.org/support/article/debugging-in-wordpress/) to quickly see any warning/error messages generated by your code.

Comment: @cabrerahector looking at your comments, your corrections sound right as well. But, how can I check if a checkbox has been check through the functions.php inside the hook I am using?